# How do I download a file from another website using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found the script on web from [johnculviner.com](http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/) for downloading the file to "download" folder .
It does saves the file. However, when I create my a tag, the file is opened and not save.
Would someone help me to solve it. Thanks in advance.

there is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Test</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />    
      <script src="jquery.fileDownload.js></script>

     <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
        
     $(function() {
     $(document).on("click", "a.fileDownloadTest", function() {
          $.fileDownload($(this).attr('href'), {
           preparingMessageHtml: "We are preparing your report, please wait...",
           failMessageHtml: "There was a problem generating your report, please try again.",
           download: "true"

      });
      return false; 
     });
});
  </script>

</head>
<body>

  <a href="https://tes.ca/get/?Ticket=QJcrdyCfoyt" class="fileDownloadTest" target="_blank">test.pdf</a>
  <br />
  <br />

  <a href="http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/FileDownload/DownloadReport/0" class="fileDownloadTest">Report0.pdf</a>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That plugin isn't capable of doing what you want without modifications.

Comment: your not preventDefault'ing on the link. You have a missing quote in `<script src="jquery.fileDownload.js></script>` have you checked console for errors?

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure all you need to do is add the "download" attribute to your a tag to make it downloadable.
Hope this helps.

Comment: @MyferreDrinkBeer, I added the download attribute in my code, but it is same.

Comment: @user819774 that plugin has no such 'download' setting. You didn't add a download attribute to an anchor tag.